# PHP ucwords working on all but first word?

Tags: php

I have this simple string:

```
echo ucwords("<row><cell><chars class='subHeader'><value>how much time do you spend</value></chars></cell></row>");
```

But its outputting like so:

```
<row>
<cell>
<chars Class="subHeader">
<value>how Much Time Do You Spend</value>
</chars>
</cell>
</row>
```

Comment: It's not treating that as a word because it's immediately prefixed by the tags. Not sure what can be done without starting to parse the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your HTML is that simple like in the input, specifically being US-ASCII encoded and not containing any CDATA sections, this might work:

```
$str = "<row><cell><chars class='subHeader'><value>how much time do you spend</value></chars></cell></row>";

$str = str_replace('>', '> ', $str);
$str = ucwords($str);
$str = str_replace('> ', '>', $str);

echo $str;
```

This does work because `>` is a reserved character in HTML. Adding a space after each will make `ucwords` to work as documented. After `ucwords` has done it's job, the change is reverted.

However this might bring you into problems if `>` sequences existed earlier which will be removed as well. So take care.

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible, you'll want to change your code to:

```
echo "<row><cell><chars class='subHeader'><value>" . ucwords("how much time do you spend") . "</value></chars></cell></row>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's outputting that, and not `<row><cell><chars Class='subHeader'><value>how Much ...`, note the uppercase C on `Class`. My guess is that `ucwords()` operates on space-delimited words.